# C++ pointer handling

Tags: c++

Suppose I create a form using a pointer and that form contains sub item as another pointer, when I delete the form, I perform a delete operation on the main pointer, do I need to perform a delete operation on the sub pointer also or the compiler does that on its own?

Comment: Form? Are we talking about .NET's WinForms?

Comment: The forms are made using Motif.

Answer (score 4):

If you're the one allocating memory for the pointer, yes, you need to explicitly release all memory you're allocating.

```
struct A
{
};

struct B
{
   A* a;
   B() { a = new A; }
   ~B();
};

B* b = new B;
delete b;
//you will have a memory leak here, since the memory pointed to by b.a 
//is not released
```

The proper way is freeing the memory in the destructor:

```
struct B
{
   A* a;
   B() { a = new A; }
   ~B() { delete a; }
};
```

You should read up on smart pointers, they might suit your case better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll normally need to delete that explicitly to avoid a memory leak. Simple rule: if you used `new` to allocate it, you'll need a matching `delete` to free it.

That said, you usually want to use something like a smart pointer that handles all this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This question hinges on the way the destructor for the form is written. For example, the form may try to call the destructor for the sub-form. If it performs this kind of cleanup then you do not need to further release the sub-form. It would be informative to know what form management system you are talking about (for example MFC).

Comment: The forms are made using Motif.